# Gas leak smell from Harley

Tags: leak, gasoline

I have a 2017 HD Breakout with 7,000km on the clock.  It is emitting a strong smell of gas from the top of engine.  The injectors have been looked at with no issue.  There is no petrol leak no loss of power no popping no hissing.  The smell can be really strong and I can even taste it.  Have u any ideas at all thanks?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you checked the fuel cap is sealing properly?

Comment: Also, does it still smell like gas when the fuel level is low?

Comment: Fuel cap is all good and the gas smell is strong no matter at what level